# Adding individual product pages for ruby on rails e-commerce site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view

Hi I am having trouble showing an individual page for a product on ruby on rails for an e-commerce site, my code is as follows for the show view:

```
<div class="name">
  <%= @product.name %>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <%= @product.description %>
</div>

<div class="images">

<div class="image_url">
<%= @product.image_url %>
</div>

<div class="image_url1">
  <%= @product.image_url1 %>
</div>

<div class="image_url2">
  <%= @product.image_url2 %>
</div>

<div class="image_url3">
  <%= @product.image_url3 %>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="price" >
   <%= @product.price %>
 </p>
```

Here is the code for the controller:

```
def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
format.html # show.html.erb
format.json { render json: @product}
end
end
```

What should I add to be able to see an individual products page which shows the name images, description, price as it works fine when I am indexing the products?

Comment: are you seeing any error with this code? did you create a route for the product?

Comment: This is what I get back: 'Name: Duffer

Product Description: Here is a duffer bag

Image URL: rails.png

Image URL 1:

Image URL 2:

Image URL 3:

Price: 100.0'  But What I want are the images to be displayed which is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `<img>` tag to show an image, which can be generated with the `image_tag` method.
Try this:

```
<div class="image_url">
  <%= image_tag(@product.image_url) %>
</div>
```

[Here's more information on the image_tag method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)

You may also want to hide that `div` if one of the images doesn't exist:

```
<% if !@product.image_url3.nil? && !@product.image_url3.blank? %>
  <div class="image_url3">
    <%= image_tag(@product.image_url3) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: are you sure that the `image_url` field contains a valid url? did you try checking that url through the browser?

Comment: Basically I am following the Agile web development in Ruby book and following the depot example, but to extend my knowledge I am making improvements. Basically a customer clicks on an image they are then redirected to the products page which is where I am stuck on, showing the images of that product.

Comment: You need your view to generate an [html `img` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp). This is done in Rails via the `image_tag` method. If I had to guess, I'd say that you don't have valid urls in the database. Try connecting to your database and adding some urls to existent images.

Comment: The rails.png exists in the database and is stored in the assets folder.

Comment: Then use your browser to see the generated source code for the page. It should have this: `<img src="rails.png" />`

Comment: It comes up as this `<p>
 <b> Image URL:</b>
   rails.png
</p>` which is not right

Comment: That code is not part of the view you showed above. Is this the code for product/show.html.erb?

Comment: what I did was use the show route from products to show an individual product . Would it make sense to make a show for store instead.

Comment: No, it's ok. The show route from products is supossed to show an individual product.

Comment: I am still stuck with this not sure what to do now , as I have looked at other examples where this has been done but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work finally I was making changes to the wrong view file.